# Using SELECTEDVALUE in PowerBI

Tags: list, powerbi, selectedvalue

I have a table that contains the sample data from the attached image.

[image: sample data]

The sample table can be interpreted as follows: I have a list of customers with Customer_id, Customer_name and Email that have an account on 1 or more e-commerce sites. Every e-commerce site can be identified by the EcommerceSite_Id column.
If a customer has more than one account (eg: on EcommerceSite_Id = 111 and also on EcommerceSite_Id = 112) the GlobalClient_Id will have the same value (e.g. John has an account on the following EcommerceSite_Id: 111, 113 and 114. Therefore, he has the same GlobalClient_Id – “11” which is attributed based on some automatic criteria – in this example, email address).

What I want to achieve:

By using a slicer with the EcommerceSite_Id column, when selecting the EcommerceSite_Id 114, it should display all customers with a unique email address, that do not have an account in 114, by taking into account the GlobalClient_Id.

Therefore, the output should be

[image: Output]:

Therefore, as you can see I excluded the following customer_ids: 5 and 9. They do not have an account on 114, but I excluded them because they have the same ClientGlobal_Id with customers_ids 10 and 8, customers that have an account on 114.

I cannot find a solution. I tried to use selected values, but I don’t know if I am using it correctly.

Can you please give me an idea on how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. Here's one solution that might work for you:

**Step 1.** EcommerceSite_Id needs to be added to a separate table - it will contain distinct IDs:

[image]

Here's how the data model should look like:

[image]

**Step 2.** Create a measure

For each client, the measure will count the number of rows where a chosen EcommerceSite_Id appeared:

```
mExclude = 
    var EcommerceSite = SELECTEDVALUE(ES[EcommerceSite_Id])
    var ThisCustomer = SELECTEDVALUE(CustomerData[Customer_name])
    var Check = COUNTROWS(FILTER(ALL(CustomerData), CustomerData[Customer_name] = ThisCustomer && CustomerData[EcommerceSite_Id] = EcommerceSite))
return
    Check + 0
```

When added to a table, and having a single EcommerceSite_Id selected (use your new table as a slicer), you get the following results:

[image]

**Step 3.** Finishing up

Finally, remove mExclude form the table and add it to the table filters. Set it up to filter values that are equal to zero.

[image]

The final result:

[image]